# What does this called in iOS?

Tags: ios, button, menu

picture1:
[image: picture1]

picture2:
[image: picture2]

I want to know how does the three horizontal dots called in iOS in picture1. I need to add two buttons in it and add actions for these two buttons like picture two. I am new to iOS developing, any help is appreciated!

---

Comment: `Settings` ? :D

Comment: I think not, I know in Android it is called overflow action.

Comment: I don't really understand the question... you mean the overflow layer with buttons or the button that calls it?

Comment: `UIActionSheet` And `UIBarButtonItem` >>`navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem`

Comment: I want to add it in my navigation bar, but I don't know how to call it so I cannot find the right guide about it, I mean the overflow layer with buttons.

Comment: Refer this link for bar button item action https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765449/how-to-give-barbuttonitem-action

Answer (score 0):

Those three dot is bar button item(can also be a Button). The actions shown is from a UIAlertController. Refer this official link on UIAlertController https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller

You can modify the style of the alert controller to action sheet which is shown in the above picture.

Answer (score 0):

That is a "more" button. If the three dots are up and down instead of across it is called a "vertical more" button. It just means there wasn't enough room/space to fit all the buttons so one or more are hidden. Pressing this button reveals the buttons that wouldn't fit.